# Construct or build a mathematical model?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the proper verb to use when I want to say that I "made" a mathematical model? I would love to hear more than one answer. Are construct \ built OK?

Comment: There isn't a single term.  Many words for the concept are commonly used--construct, build, develop, create, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be too short of an answer but here it goes:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model):

> The process of developing a mathematical model is termed mathematical
>   modeling.

Since the process of *developing a mathematical model* has ended for you, I'd say you have *developed a mathematical model!*